# Why are there more opposite sign events than same-sign ones in the QCD background of three-prong tau decays?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, data-analysis, electroweak

So im dealing with three-prong tau decays. Specifically, two taus are produced via the Drell-Yan process and one decays leptonicly into a muon and the other decays hadronicly into three charged pions (three prong).
So my question is, when modelling the QCD background, when I apply a filter that only accepts events, where the charge of the decays products is opposite to one another (+-) I have more events than when I only accept same sign events (++ or --). Why is there more opposite sign QCD background? I was under the assumption that charge needn't be opposite in QCD background because its a qcd process and not an electroweak process. What am I missing here? Let me know if the problem is unclear and ill elaborate.